# SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE error when sending mail in Gmail Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl

Hello to the community I tell them that I am working with XAMPP for utilzando apache module for PHP development in version 5.6.

In my case I'm trying to send mail to Gmail, but it is generating an error of this type: **SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE**

Code PHP:

```
$config = array();
// The mail sending protocol.
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
// SMTP Server Address for Gmail.
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
// SMTP Port - the port that you is required
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
// SMTP Username like. (abc@gmail.com)
$config['smtp_user'] = 'mailtest123@gmail.com';
// SMTP Password like (abc***##)
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'test123';

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = true;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822


// Load email library and passing configured values to email library
$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from('hernando123@gmail.com', 'Hernando');
$this->email->to('hernando567@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('TEST SEND 09-10');
$this->email->message('TEST SEND 09-10 LLLLL.');

if ($this->email->send()) {
    log_message('debug', '-----> Mail Sent!');
} else {
    log_message('debug', '-----> There is error in sending mail!');
}
```

Error PHP:

```
ERROR - 2015-10-09 03:46:45 --> Severity: Warning --> fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed C:\xampp\htdocs\accounts\system\libraries\Email.php 1949
ERROR - 2015-10-09 03:46:45 --> Severity: Warning --> fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto C:\xampp\htdocs\accounts\system\libraries\Email.php 1949
ERROR - 2015-10-09 03:46:45 --> Severity: Warning --> fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unknown error) C:\xampp\htdocs\accounts\system\libraries\Email.php 1949
DEBUG - 2015-10-09 03:46:45 --> -----> There is error in sending mail!
```

As I researched, on this page: https://kamihouse.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/verificacao-de-certificado-ssl-com-php-5-6/

Add a file folder **XAMPP** wing, and you map in **php.ini**

```
openssl.cafile = "C:\xampp\ssl\cert.pem"
```

[http://es.tinypic.com/r/jt9vyv/8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq4DH.png)

But I do not work the same, I hope you can help me in my case, thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**I found the answer in this post:**  http://punto50.blogspot.pe/2015/03/envio-de-correo-con-phpmailer-y-gmail.html

Comment: This answer is not even about CodeIgniter 3. Have some legitimacy please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load email library before $config setting

```
 $this->load->library('email');
   $config=array(
            'charset'=>'utf-8',
            'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
            'mailtype' => 'html'
            );
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

You are loading library in middle.
For more try this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-send-email-using-codeigniter/